# squid-deb-proxy-client working on trusty but not on xenial

Tags: networking, apt, upgrade, package-management, proxy

I am upgrading various laptops to Xenial (16.04) and have installed squid-deb-proxy on a raspberry-pi (raspbian-jessie) that I have doing various things and is the only system I have on all the time. I have installed the squid-deb-proxy-client on my Trusty 14.04 and this works fine, I can watch the cache working via an ssh terminal with `$ sudo tail -F /var/log/squid-deb-proxy/access.log`

Having done the first re-install on another laptop (moving from 14.10 to 16.04, keeping home folder, scripts to reinstall all previously installed packages) I do

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install squid-deb-proxy-client
```

but when I `$ sudo apt-get upgrade` it is ignoring the cache on the fresh new Xenial installation.

I noticed someone else had a problem with ipv6 and a proxy, so I've disabled ipv6 by adding 3 lines to sysctl.conf:

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

no change. I also upgraded apt to the latest version.

I'd like to avoid downloading all the upgrading and installing packages multiple times (>400Mb each time) on my limited data allowance ... any ideas why is this not working? anything else that needs to be updated or changed from the DVD release versions to allow the proxy to work on Xenial?

Update: the proxy is working fine, but ONLY WHEN I AM RUNNING WIRESHARK TO WATCH THE PROTOCOLS! if I start Wireshark while it is working I can see the tail end of transfers coming direct from the server but the next apt-get works with the proxy. If I quit Wireshark, the next apt-get goes direct. Now if I can work out what effect Wireshark is having...